# Android - force searchview to open programmatically

Tags: java, android

In my application am using the library for the autoComplete searchview
Here is what the library am using

```
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
```

Here is my xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

What I want is I want to open the searchView programmatically to open searchbar without using pressing the search icon in `actionbar`.
How can i achieve this.any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use inbuilt functionality of autocompletetextview which this library must be extending

```
search_view.setFocusedByDefault(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I observed the library and MaterialSearchView class i see there one method it is showSearch(). may be it is for show SearchView.

method is in MaterialSearchView.class

```
public void showSearch(boolean animate) {
if (isSearchOpen()) {
   return;
}
```

So you can call this method like this :

```
materialSearchView.showSearch(true/false);
```

May be work for your requirement. Hope this help you.

Comment: app getting crashed while using this method